# Find out the true creator/owner of a Google project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to housekeep some projects in my organisation. The accounts I found associated with these projects are service accounts, no G Suite user IDs that I expect. How to I find out the real creator/owner of these accounts so that I could contact them to clean these projects up? Thanks.

```
gcp@newagent-c6975:~$ gcloud projects get-iam-policy journey-1
bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:231068496079-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
  - serviceAccount:journey-1@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/editor
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service-231068496079@sourcerepo-service-accounts.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/sourcerepo.serviceAgent
etag: BwVcDntoAd0=
version: 1

gcp@newagent-c6975:~$ gcloud projects get-iam-policy myproject-158702
bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:303108974603-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/editor
etag: BwVOUItnYrU=
version: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open Stackdriver Logging, and on the text box where you would paste the expression to search, select in the dropdown menu the option: "Convert to advanced filter" and paste this query:

```
resource.type="service_account"
protoPayload."@type"="type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"
protoPayload.methodName="google.iam.admin.v1.CreateServiceAccountKey"
```

This will return who created the services accounts on that project.